# Is there an equivalent of the "King's rule" for sum?

Tags: integration, summation

For integrals, there exists a formula (the "King's rule") :

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\textrm{d}x=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)\textrm{d}x$

Does it exist a sum counterpart ? Something like :

$\sum\limits_{a}^bf(x)=\sum\limits_{a}^bf(a+b-x)$

If it exists, could you provide a proof and possibly the name of this property, or at least a link ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it’s fairly standard to say: $$\sum_{j=k}^na_j=\sum_{j=k}^na_{n-j+k}$$

The proof is clear. Every summand on the LHS appears on the RHS and visa versa, with no repetitions. *Finite* summation is independent of the order.

Comment: So the mapping is $\sigma(j)=n-j+k$ ? Does this property have a name ?

Comment: @Fnifni Not that I know of, it’s too ‘trivial’ to have a name I think.